# I am trying to add backtick for starting of the row and end of the row which is having special character at the end

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to add backtick for starting of the row and end of the row which is having special character at the end. what is the best way to do that in unix.

Records:

abcd

efkd

efbc

efdg

edfg

edfm

edfg#

edek

edfmk

edfgk

expected output:

abcd

efkd

efbc

efdg

edfg

edfm

`edfg#` --> this row has to populated with back quote in starting of the row and

ending of the row

edek

edfmk

edfgk

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have tried this with most `unix` utils already, you need to know that an unquoted `backquote` had special meaning to the shell. You'll be causing yourself a lot of trouble to insist on using data with an embedded backquote in a script. BUT be sure any statment is like `sed 's/XXX/&[\`]/' file` (note that the backquote is inside of single quotes. The shell will not try to process it there as a special char. Good luck.

Comment: Please make your sample data and required output much smaller. We only need 3 lines (max). Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on selected text to get correct formattiong for code/data/errMsgs/Etc. AND as StackOverflow uses the back-quote char for it's formatting, use a `#` char for start and end. Indicate that you will really be doing the back-quote. You  should also include your best attempt to solve your problem.We won't do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: $ sed s/^.*#/#&#/g; filename

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.+)#$/\`\1\`/' < data_file > result_file
```